# Why if i change some characters of a Public key on authorizedKeys the login still works

Tags: rsa, public-key, authentication, ssh

This question is similar to:
[1]
[Why does my SSH private key still work after changing some bytes in the file?](https://crypto.stackexchange.com/questions/31807/why-does-my-ssh-private-key-still-work-after-changing-some-bytes-in-the-file)

But in this case (on Windows) after editing the authorized_keys file and changing some characters in a public key the login still works ?

Is the same reason of [1] ? 
Some characters in the public key are irrelevant ?

In this case the correct key is:
ssh-rsa AAAAB3NzaC1....
IF i change it to (replace C1 with C9):
ssh-rsa AAAAB3NzaC9...

The login works, if i change AAAA then it does not work any more.

Comment: It'll be essentially the same answer. Not all of the encoded information is needed for the login to work. They have purposes, but not for every use.

Comment: Similar to this [Can an altered RSA private key still work as the original?](https://crypto.stackexchange.com/q/88364/18298)

Comment: Much closer to (cross) https://serverfault.com/questions/526399/why-do-my-two-ssh-public-keys-have-the-same-beginning/526404 . The 5th through 11th bytes in the binary blob, corresponding to part of 6th, all of 7th through 14th, and part of 15th characters in the base64, are a redundant copy of the format (previously algorithm) name and are ignored. And not really about cryptography at all.